# Refused to connect to x because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive (connect-src)

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, heroku, content-security-policy

I deployed a MERN app on heroku and I set these values for the CSP:

```html
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="connect-src https://api.themoviedb.org 'self'; default-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; object-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' ; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com"
    />
```

However this is what I get in Chrome console:

**Refused to connect to [URL] because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.**

Why does it tell me that connect-src was not set, when I can see it in the index.html when I inspect the page?

Answer (score -12, accepted):

CSP has versions (or levels) with newly supported features extending the original spec.
Serving the CSP through an html meta header is considered legacy and has some drawbacks.
**Try setting CSP via the HTTP headers of the request**
Also, as a best practice make the `default-src` you first directive.

Comment: After removing the html meta header and adding an HTTP header instead, it worked! Thank you

Comment: @SimeriaIonut how did you do that? currently facing the same issue

Comment: Post your solution so others can benefit from it aswell!

Comment: I had the same problem with electron react and removing the meta tag from index.html worked with firebase

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63869166) marked as "right answer", is completely wrong and provides misleading information.

1. A `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy>` meta tag **is not** considered as legacy.
   In some cases, the meta tag is the only way to delivery the policy to the page.
2. > best practice make the default-src you first directive.

   Nonsense. Order of directives in CSP has no any meaning. Moreover, Google's [strict CSP](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html) does not have a `default-src` directive at all.
3. The question author's issue is that `node.js` includes Helmet middleware in dependencies. Helmet v4 publishes a [default CSP HTTP header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp) which does not have `connect-src` directive.
   That's why the question author observes below message:

   > Refused to connect to [URL] because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "**default-src 'self'**". Note that **'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback**.

**Note** that it's not a CSP rules from meta tag, but a default CSP rules by Helmet middleware.

Mitigating that default CSP by adding a second CSP via meta tag does fail because of 2 CSPs do applied at the same time - all sources should pass through both CSP.

So there are two options:

- Disable Helmet `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy()` and use meta tag to deliver CSP.
- Remove meta tag CSP and add `connect-src` rules into `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

If you are using a server-side framework, such as Express.js, you can add the Content-Security-Policy header to the HTTP response using the helmet middleware. Here's an example of how to add the CSP header with connect-src set to allow connections to 'self' and http://127.0.0.1:8000 as well as ws://localhost:42877/:

```
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      connectSrc: ["'self'", 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', 'ws://localhost:42877/']
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved the day. I thoght it was a react thing all day long